# Open popup onclick and closing it on submit and display relevant html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, popup

I have a scenario, if I click a next button on an html page it opens a popup. The popup has username and password. After providing username and password if I click submit button, the popup should close and go to a next html page. Using only JavaScript or jQuery. My Code: HTML: JS:
My Code:

```
HTML:
<input class="btnFont floatRight" name="__DONE_BUTTON" type="button" onClick="myFunction();" value="Next">
JS:
<script>

    function myFunction() {

    var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=279, height=150");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>User ID:</p><input type='text' width='30px'>");

    myWindow.document.write("<p>Password:</p><input type='password' width='30px'>");
    myWindow.document.write("<input type='button' value='OK' width='30px'>");

}
```

Comment: Not sure a popup is the right solution, as all modern browsers have built-in popup killers.

Comment: rather than a new popup window, why not try a light box and you'll avoid the problem of the popup being blocked.

Comment: You should avoid popups! Quote for @iliketolearn solution!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for like a bootstrap modal, here you can close with

```
 window.close();
```

and redirect with

```
$(window).attr("location","/test/tes1");
```